# How can I view the object in 2D in the front view

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I'm a newbie to Blender, so sorry in advance if my question sounds stupid -and I'm sure it is-.

I'm working on a tutorial where I have to create one cube beside the default one. and then I have to manipulate them in the front view.

the problem is, after creating the new cube, and switching back to front view I see the cubes in 3D dimensions, not 2.

[image: This is what I get]

while in the tutorial this is what I should expect:

[image]

could you please assist me what's wrong?

Comment: Just press 5 on numpad

Comment: Note that by default when hitting Numpad 1 to enter Front view orthographic mode is enabled and used automatically, but this can be turned off in the User prefs > Interface > Auto Perspective; if it's unchecked, there won't be orthographic mode used when entering Front View so maybe that's the case in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have been in the front perspective mode instead of front orthographic mode. You just have to press numpad '5' key to get to orthographic mode.

Front perspective looks like this and you can see that on the top left of the screen.
[image]

Front ortho looks like this. Again, its mentioned in the top left of the screen.
[image]

If you don't have a numpad in your keyboard.Press Ctrl+Alt+U for preferences and enable 'emulate numpad' in the 'Input' tab. And then, instead of numpad 5, you can just press the normal '5' to get to orthographic mode.

[image]

Comment: You can also find it in the view menu of the 3D viewport.